# Can I convert my steam keys to gift copies?

Tags: steam

Can I convert my steam keys to gift copies, so that I can trade it?

Doing so would be very convenient as it'd reduce potential of scamming when trading items with steam keys.

Is doing so possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't, as these discussions on Steam forums point out:

- [How to turn steam game key into a tradeable gift key](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/492379159715715194/)
- [KEYS for games to gifts](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/619569608695562654/)

It is not possible to change a key to a gift in your inventory. To have a gift in your inventory, you must either receive it from another player, or choose the option "Buy as a gift" while purchasing the game.

Comment: but why doesnt valve/steam add that option? it would be so usefull for safe trading

Comment: @SakshamGoyal Why would they be interested in supporting trading keys?

Comment: @SakshamGoyal If Steam/Valve can't make money on it, it is not interesting. Thus, if they did something like a "tax" on all trades, players wouldn't use it. Kind of answered your question, I guess

Comment: @SakshamGoyal I doubt steam has a license to do that.  Selling games is more complicated than just buying a set of the files to do whatever you want with (not always the case, but often or always is with steam games).  There are agreements with publishers on who can access them, how they are used, how they are shared etc.  Steam would likely be violating publisher agreements by doing this.